# Downgrading numpy 1.12.1 to 1.10.1

Tags: package-management, python

I am very new to Unix and this may be a basic question but I couldn't figure out.

```
$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
1.12.1 

$ pip uninstall numpy==1.12.1
Cannot uninstall requirement numpy, not installed

$ pip install numpy==1.10.1
Collecting numpy==1.10.1
  Using cached numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.10.1

$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
1.12.1
```

There are three python installed in this computer and the first one is default.

```
/sw/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

I tried changing path to use different python but all of them show numpy 1.12.1 when I cannot even uninstall because it's not installed.

Anyone has any clue?

---

Update
I tried updating numpy then,

`$ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.13.0rc2
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.13.0rc2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Requires:`

`$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.version.version)"
1.12.1`

I don't have permission to remove 1.13.0

So does this mean that my current python is running with numpy 1.13.0?

Comment: What OS? Maybe numpy was installed through the distro packaging mechanism and not through pip?

Comment: It's OS Sierra 10.12.5

Comment: So can you find out if the package manager of your OS did the numpy installation? On RPM systems, it would be something `yum list installed *numpy` but I don't know what the equivalent on your OS would be. If it was installed by the package manager, then try downgrading or updating `numpy` with the package manager, rather than with `pip`.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your response! I happen to solve this problem just now.
I edited bash_profile and changed PYTHONPATH into /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages and finally it works! I still don't understand fully but it seems that my current python is running with downgraded numpy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

1.
`--upgrade` can be used for both downgrade or upgrade:

`pip install --upgrade numpy==1.10.1`

2.
I would prefer uninstall existing numpy package and install required one

Uninstall the numpy using pip

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

And

Install the numpy using upgrade pip command. You can ever upgrade or downgrade

```
pip install --upgrade numpy==1.10.1
```